# Is there anyway to store files in a NoSQL db and store the link to the file(of NoSQL) in my PostgreSQL db?

Tags: database, postgresql, nosql, filesystems

I am working on an assignment which needs to store the files uploaded by the user. I thought of storing it in the filesystem and store the path in the DB. Usually the files will be within 5MB.

I have a doubt whether I can store the file in a NoSQL db and give the reference of the NoSQL db(the file) in my Postgre DB. Kinldy help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `FOREIGN DATA WRAPPERS` in postgresql?

Postgresql allows you to store and access data that resides outside postgresql's storage via ForeignDataWrappers. FDWs are like extensions to postgresql. You can piggy back on the postgresql's SQL standards and store the data in you wrapper. Such tables are called `FOREIGN TABLES`.

From the docs,

> A foreign table can be used in queries just like a normal table, but a
>   foreign table has no storage in the PostgreSQL server.

There are various FDWs available for NoSQLs. Refer [link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers)

More about [FDWs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html)